# minDate not working in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using this bootstrap datepicker http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dateToday = new Date();
$(function() {
    $("#id_deadline").datepicker({minDate: dateToday});
});
</script>
```

I want to let select the date from today to future only (not a past date). Datepicker is showing up and it is letting me select the past date too. What's wrong?

Comment: You might want to check this out http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: I ended up using `jQuery picker`. It worked.

Answer (score 26):

Try using that way:

```
$("#id_deadline").datepicker({ startDate: "today" });
```

There is no need a Date var for using startDate parameter.

Answer (score 7):

try using `startDate` with this way :

```
$("#id_deadline").datepicker({startDate: new Date()});
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: this worked for the version of bootstrap I'm using and not the minDate one.

Comment: yeah same thing i look for i'm using old version there is mindate is not working.

Answer (score 6):

Since none of the answers worked for me. I managed to disable to older dates by using **onRender** option

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
          onRender: function(date) {
            return date.valueOf() < new Date().valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

My code is Bootstrap Datetimepicker (mindate) Functionality related.
        My code is working in all browser like ff,chrome and ie also.
    Please check below example. Working for me.

```
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            //minDate: new Date() + 1,
            minDate:moment(),
            Default: true,
            defaultDate: new Date(),
            pickTime: false,
            use24hours: false,
            format: 'MM-DD',
            icons: {
                time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                date: "fa fa-calendar",
                up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
            },
            //   minDate: moment(+1),
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

try,

```js
var dateToday = new Date(); 
$(function () {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      autoclose: true,
      startDate: dateToday
    });
});
```

Backdate

```js
var last7Days = new Date(); 
last7Days.setDate(last7Days.getDate()-7);
$(function () {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: last7Days
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Following should work:
minDate: new Date()

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to limit datepicker min/max date after initialization (for example when some event fires), you can use:
[setStartDate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setstartdate) or [setEndDate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setenddate) like following:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setStartDate', new Date());
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setEndDate', new Date());
```

See method usage docs: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#methods

Answer (score 0):

you can use following working code which disables all the past dates-

for DatePicker [working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ManojSalvi/7kfxvshu/)

```
$(function () {
  //get Today's Date
  var currDate = new Date();
  $('#datetimepicker').datepicker({
    startDate : currDate
  });
});
```

and for DateTimePicker this would work ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ManojSalvi/65vaoqkw/9/))-

```
$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate : moment()
  });
});
```

Comment: Your solution is for datetimepicker, OP wanted it for datepicker. Whatever, you solution is correct for datetimepicker.

Answer (score 0):

I to spent some time looking through the documentation in search for this option. The bootstrap datepicker comes with a [startDate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate) option that will accept dates or strings, from the documentation:

> Date should be in local timezone. String must be parsable with `format`

There is an [online demo](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) that lets you try out different options. If you enter `now` (or `new Date()`) in the startDate field, the datepicker will not let you select a date before the current date.

The little code output at the side will then show you the code you need to use in you website, in this case that would be:

```js
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
    startDate: "now"
});
```

You do need to switch the `#sandbox-container input` part for a selector that points to your datepicker element.