# bootstrap jquery minDate not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, mindate

I want to disable all dates before today in a bootstrap `datepicker`. I have digged the internet and everyone has this solution but why is it not working in my code?

```
<input type="text" id="date"/>
```

```js
$(window).load(function(){
   $('#date').datepicker({
        minDate:0
   });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [minDate not working in bootstrap datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219713/mindate-not-working-in-bootstrap-datepicker)

Comment: minDate 0 why? could it be full date string of today?

Comment: @ankit I even tried startDate as suggested in that possible duplicate of yours. Its still not working!!!

Comment: @George Garchagudashvili What according to should there be if i want to disable previous dates in a date picker??

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31426675/3172092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtdate").datepicker({
            minDate: 0
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
Date :
<input id="txtdate" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check once again I updated my code. Otherwise paste your complete code so that anyone can modify it.

Comment: doesnt work. possibly i am using bootstrap 2 in which this mindate doesnt work. Do you have a solution for bootstrap 2.

Comment: I am confused so that I am telling you if its possible just add some more code so then only I can verify it otherwise its very difficult to find-out.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/ZL2Bc/ here is a simple example in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
    /* Apply the right format to the minDate option */
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtdate").datepicker({
            minDate: new Date();
        });
    });
```